# function of a diagonal matrix

Tags: matrices

I sit for quite a while now for the following exercise.
Let D and E be diagonal matrices, T and S transformation matrices which are invertable. A is a matrix which can be transformed to $A=TDT^{-1}$

I have to show that if 
$A=TDT^{-1}=SES^{-1}$ 
it follows that 
$Tf(D)T^{-1}=Sf(E)S^{-1}$, where f is a function in the complex field that takes in a matrix instead of a variable. It is defined as: $f(A)=Tf(D)T^{-1}$, so that f(D) is a matrix with diagonal entries equal to $f(d_{11})$, for example.
So far I deduced that if the first equation holds, we get XD=EX, where X denotes the matrix one gets by $S^{-1}T$. I then showed that is X is invertible and rewrote that as $D=XEX^{-1}$. I tried to insert that into $f(D)=f(XEX^{-1}$) which leads to $Xf(E)X^{-1}$.
From this step I do not know how to continue.
Thank you for any hints!

Comment: Try to calculate ($TDT^{-1})^k$ (notice how $TT^{-1}$ cancel) Then any polynomial expansion, then any function. now take f on l.h.s.and r.h.s. of what you want to prove

Comment: Sorry, I can`t quite follow the second part. If I take f on l.h.s and r.h.s I do not see anything cancelling ;-(

Comment: you know $f(TDT^{-1})=f(SES^{-1})$ assume f is a power. then a polynom, then use that any funciton (well under som conditions on f) can be aproximated by a polynom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E=S^{-1}TDT^{-1}S$, with $\left(S^{-1}T\right)^{-1}=T^{-1}S$, so by definition $f(E)=S^{-1}Tf(D)T^{-1}S$, and the result follows.